# Compare Mysql data with python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table T1

```
id     Value1  Value2   Value3   Compared  Related
---------------------------------------------------
af02 |  AAA  |   BBB  |  CCC   |    1     |   1
ff02 |  ABA  |   BBB  |  CAC   |    1     |  af02
h2f0 |  AAB  |   BBA  |  CCA   |    0     |   0
```

Id is not auto-increment, values 1 to 3 are textual i need to compare Value2 of all rows that are not compared (0) with all other Value2 to see if the text is the same, if it is similar i need to add the id of the similar row to the Related column, and if not i need add 1 in the Related column, i need to accomplish this with python and mysql

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem?  If you post your code then we can suggest improvements.  Have a look at the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

As far as mysql is concerned that is where i dont know where to start

As for comparison i will use cosine comparison of the readed values from the db
something like this:

```
train_set = [item['Value2'][i]] 
test_set = [item['Value2'][i+=1]]
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
transformer = TfidfTransformer()

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
cx = lambda a, b: round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 3)

for vector in trainVectorizerArray:
    for testV in testVectorizerArray:
        cosine = cx(vector, testV)
        print cosine
```

And i will use the cosine value to determine the similarity and the link